# VBA Text in cell search and change font

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to figure out a way to use instr() on a cell by comparing it to another one(Directly to the left).  Basically what I want to do is if I have a cell in A1 that says "I love cookies.  Hello world.  SO is awesome."  and in A2 I have "I love cookies. Hello World.  VBA is cool. SO is awesome"  the macro will change the font of "VBA is cool" to red and keep the other words as is.  I understand how instr works, I just have problem classifying the sentence as a variable to use in instr.

I have just tried recording a macro by just changing the font of one sentence to understand how that works but unsure on how to make it so the macro recognizes changes in the second cell.

Comment: The formatting will need to be done on a character basis, you will need to determine where the substring starts and how long it is, and then format only those characters in the cell. for example `Range("A1").Characters(Start:=30, Length:=11).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Classifying a sentence in a string as a variable in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153438/classifying-a-sentence-in-a-string-as-a-variable-in-vba)

Comment: Suppose you could work with the Split() function on both with a bunch of variables to keep track where you are in each array returned by the split, how many characters you've got, etc. together with what Cybernetic said.