# Classifying a sentence in a string as a variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering how to classify a variable as a string from a sentence in a cell.
Currently I just have:

```
dim s as string
dim f as string

s = "Look Here.  This is fun."  
         
'Need to change the s variable to a sentence in cell and then figure a way to iterate through sentences in the cell
    
n = InStr(1, s, ".")  '
f = Left(s, n - 1)
```

I really am stuck here on how to get the cell string and put it in here in order to take the sentence out.  I will have to eventually iterate through the sentences as I am comparing them to sentences in other strings.  If this is possible please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: `s = Range("A1").Value`, changing `A1` as necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume all sentences end with a period and there is at least one space separating each sentence.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim s As String, arr, i As Long
'    s = Trim(Cells(1, 1).Value)
    s = "Look Here.  This is fun." ' For Testing
    arr = Split(s , ". ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If Len(Trim(arr(i))) > 0 Then _
        Debug.Print Trim(arr(i)) & "."
    Next
End Sub
```

Regular expressions (RegExp) can be used to handle splitting the text into sentences, even for complex cases.